# How can i add spans after input tags in django without rendering forms manually?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to add span tags after input tags in forms to show icons or so. the idea is in Django the forms is just rendered automatically by calling the form's context name in a template tag so is there any way I can add tags to each or only one tag without rendering the whole form manually?

can I add anything in the forms.py file to make these changes?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Crispy Forms, this plugin has nice features and more DRY than editing manually the style of django form: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/